# Chrome extension - saving login details for popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that will require the user to log into an account in order to see their content. What I want to do is prevent the user from having to log in every time by saving some kind of cookie or localStorage with relevant login/ session data once they do login.

So far after doing a bit of research it seems that using Google Chromes local storage API would be the best way of doing this (would be great if someone could confirm this).

My issue is with setting and getting local storage. I've setup a dummy local storage scenario here just to try and get Chrome to store ANY kind of local storage for the extension:

Popup.js:

```
function setCookie(){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({name: 'setLoginCookie'}, function(otherResponse) {
        console.log(otherResponse)
    })
}

function getCookie(){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({name: 'getloginCookie'}, function(response) {
        alert(response)
    })
}
```

event.js:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.name == 'setLoginCookie') {
        var obj = {test:"test"}    
        chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function() {
            alert('Data saved');
        });           
    }    

    if (request.name == 'getLoginCookie') {
           chrome.storage.sync.get('test', function(data) {
                sendResponse({ screenshotUrl: data.test });
        })       
    }
    return true;

});
```

When the setCookie function is executed I get the alert of 'data saved!' which would indicate to me it has worked but when I check the local storage on my extensions Chrome dev tools there is nothing there and if I call the `getCookie` function then it doesn't pick up anything.

Here are the permissions in my manifest.json:

```
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
   "cookies",      
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "pageCapture",
    "downloads"      
  ],
```

Have I used the wrong approach here? Is using `chrome.storage.sync` perhaps where i've gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: 1. [Inspect chrome.storage.sync while debugging Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/32471596) 2. how do you invoke getCookie?

Comment: Why are you not just storing and getting the data directly in the popup? `chrome.storage.local` is available in any page in the background context (including popups) and content scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chrome.storage.sync` is not the same thing as local storage, you won't see the data saved using this method in the dev tools **Local Storage**.

You have a message mismatch. You're using  `{name: 'getloginCookie'}` to send the message and the `if` statement is checking for `getLoginCookie`. The difference is the lower case `l` in the parameter you pass to the `sendMessage` function.

Comment: This was the issue and good spot. Silly mistake on my behalf. So would you concur that using chrome.storage.sync is the correct way to store login/ session details?

Comment: @BenLiger so did you conclude that we can use some other way to save logged in session in chrome extension?

I am clueless if not store user password in local storage than how do we store the session so as to prevent relogin?

Comment: @Hafizallylalani You can find out more about storage in chrome extensions from here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage

Comment: i should have read it before asking but there is a clear enough info now that local storage SHOULD NOT be used to store user data.

Answer (score 1):

> when I check the local storage on my extensions Chrome dev tools there is nothing there

Dev Tools do not expose `chrome.storage` inside them.

The "Local Storage" item exposes `localStorage` instead.

To inspect an extension's `chrome.storage`, you can use [Storage Area Explorer extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb?hl=en) or simply call `chrome.storage.sync.get(null, (data) => { console.log(data) })` from the console.

---

Note: you don't have to delegate working with `chrome.storage` to your Event page. `chrome.storage` is *directly accessible* from all extension contexts - background, popup, options, content scripts. Don't layer on Messaging just for this.

Comment: Ok, I just saw that the extension Last Pass have some session storage in their extension so i'm wondering how they did it!

Comment: You _can_ use `sessionStorage`/`localStorage` from inside an extension, but it's tied to domain, so it's not shared with content scripts. `chrome.storage` is a newer API that is shared across those.